# Clear data from iSeries server

Tags: windows-server-2003, disk-space-utilization

I have an iSeries serve running Windows 2003 server - let's call the server EMERALD. EMERALD is out of disk space and I cannot remotely connect to the server. I have gone to the physical server and cannot get it to recognize a keyboard/mouse so I can't connect physically either.

Any suggestions for trying to clear up some disk space? I believe not being able to remotely connect has to do with there lack of space so even if I can clear off 100-200 MB's just to get me started would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I would try and get access to the admin shares:
\\EMERALD\c$
and delete any temp files.  One (normally) big one is the windows updates folders. *C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download* for example.
BTW, If you have both data and OS files on the same volume, you should look at changing this so you don't get bit again.

Comment: I can't remotely connect to the server and when I ping it I do not get a response.

Comment: Ouch...  Another more risky approach would be to mount those drives in another Win2k3 server, or even a workstation and delete the files that way.  You will most likely have to hard shutdown the server (you may lose AD when this happens.  Do you have a backup?), but try to push the power button once and see if it initiates shutdown.  If not, hold it in for 4 seconds.